# ASME B31.3, Temporary connections?

Tags: piping

I've got a quick question related to ASME B31.3.

In my system I plan on making connections in the field for deploying the system(ie think air products LN2 tanker showing up on site and deploying flex hoses). **Is there any way to escape the leak test requirements for the new connections I'm making**

The way I understand the code is that for a pneumatic leak check I would have to perform it at 1.1 x design pressure, which really isn't feasible in the application.

Common sense is telling me that leak checking at operating pressure should be OK, just don;t know if that is in compliance with ASME B31.3

Comment: Why is 10% over the design pressure not feasible? You want some margin of error just in case whatever fluid you're piping comes in over pressure. That being said if it's not a part of the "final" assembly, or advertised as being compliant with, one could argue it's not applicable to B31.3.

Comment: Thanks ! The RV in the system is set to the design pressure. There is margin in the individual components and plumbing (their MAWP is above system design). Problem is that testing at 1.1x design pressure will pop the RV.

I appreciate the suggestion of the final assy work around, unfortunately I think it would be a hard argument to make in this case as we primarily only use the system when it is fully deployed.

I updated the question to provide a bit more context

Comment: Unfortunately I'd say you probably still need to comply, but if that's the only component that needs to be leak tested at 110% pressure you should be able to test it individually on a run of pipe with a blind flange on the other end to act as a pressure vessel.